# How to set the memory adress for an instruction in MIPS?

Tags: mips, mips32, instruction-set, spim, qtspim

Normally, the SPIM simulator itself allocates an address to the instructions in a program. Is there some way to manually choose where to store a particular instruction?

Comment: show us what you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, the `.text` directive has an optional argument where you can specify an address:

```
.text
.globl main
# This code ends up at the default address for the .text section
main:

li $a0,1
jal foo
li $v0,1
syscall

li $v0,10
syscall

.text 0x430000
# This code ends up at address 0x430000
foo:
li $a0,2
jr $ra
```

Of course you can't just pick an address at random. It must be valid for the target environment (QtSpim in my example).

---

Another possibility is to assemble everything into the default location, and then copy parts of the code into RAM at runtime and execute it from there.

Comment: What if I want to store a single instruction set out of let’s say 10 at a particular location. What exactly I need to do is somehow go to a label outside the 16 bit range of beq.